# JS Merge vs JS Bundle which one is better for Google ranking

Tags: magento2, javascript, optimization

JS bundling saves page size in MBs but bundled js loaded synchronously. And the browser waits for js download completion.

But in JS Merge Magento merges only those js which are required synchronously. And browser only waits for merged JS which is much lighter than bundled one. And rest of the JS loaded asynchronously.

Somewhere I have seen it is better to load js asynchronously if using HTTP2. And Google also recommends deferring JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After working with many Magento 2 websites I came up with JS merging with minify on works better for Google's new insight.

Also, page loads resources asynchronously which makes page rendering fast.

Comment: I would go as far as saying the bundle option has a negative scoring impact